# Docusign API Optional Signature field not showing

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the docusign api to create a signature field (signHereTabs) and when I set the "optional" parameter to "true" then this signature field is not displayed at all in the viewer.

This would be an example of the code used:

```
private SignHere CreateSignHere(String fieldName, string recipientId)
{
    return new SignHere
    {
        TabLabel = fieldName,
        RecipientId = recipientId,
        Optional = "true"
    };
}
```

And this would be a screen capture without optional set to true:

[Without optional = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkE4J.png)

And with the parameter set to true:

[With optional = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU9G9.png)

How can I have an optional signature that the user would decide to sign if needed ?

Thanks,

Hadrien REINER

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please*** check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your Envelopes:create request. To find out what, exactly, you're sending to DocuSign, use the [API logging feature](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging).

[API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Optional%20sign%20here%20tab%20with%20webhook%20XML%20notification%20and%20metadata%20) includes an optional signature example. Click the link, login with your developer account credentials, then click **Send Envelope** to try it out.

Screenshot:

[image]

JSON request:

```
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [
                {
                    "email": "signer_email@example.com",
                    "name": "Signer's name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "tabs": {
                        "signHereTabs": [
                            {
                                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                                "anchorXOffset": "20",
                                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                                "optional": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: @user1629855 Try the direct example link for an [optional signature](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Optional%20sign%20here%20tab%20with%20webhook%20XML%20notification%20and%20metadata%20)